# Reduce battery drain when playing music in background

Tags: ios, xcode-instruments

I have an app which plays white noise/ambient sounds in the background to help the user fall/stay asleep, so it's designed to run all night and play in the background and/or when the screen is locked. I'm obviously seeing battery drain as a result, but are there any steps I can take to reduce this battery drain?

The AVAudioPlayer and a few NSTimers should be the only things that are running while the app is backgrounded/screen-locked, but I'm not sure how to determine if there are any other processes running at the same time that could also be killing the battery. I'm sure something in Instruments could tell me, but I'm not sure which one to use - they seem designed to profile an app that's currently running, not one that's currently in the background.

Comment: so your question is which processes is your app running and how to find them?

Comment: Yes, but specifically which processes are running *after* I lock the screen or tap the home button.

Comment: And if there are any other tips/tricks to reducing battery drain in general.

Comment: What are the timers you're leaving running? If for example, you're using a timer to tell the user how long they were asleep, it would be much more efficient to create an NSDate object when they fall asleep and again when they wake up, and get the time interval in between them.

Comment: I do have something similar to that, yes. Is there a way to determine which NSTimers are currently running?

Answer (score 0):

Probably late on answering this, but maybe this will help someone encountering this issue recently. If you are calling a task with a Timer or NSTimer constantly in the background the energy impact may be high and causing battery drain. For example, I was updating a UISlider using Timer and that caused significant battery drain.

To better debug battery issues go to the debug navigator and select Energy Impact. that will show you if and when energy impact is high. Run your app and view Energy Impact to see the issue. Then comment out the timer and run to see if energy impact is still high. Hope this helps someone.

[image: Energy Impact Chart]